# How to match vector of strings with dataframe column in r

Tags: r

I have a vector of column like following

```
   a = "ASDRT" "GTYHE" "AQWER" QWERT"
```

And I have a dataframe like following

```
      ID.           Amount

   SDFGH.       45
   ASDRT.        67
   AQWER.      88
   TYUIIO.        543
   QWERT.        32
```

I want to match vector values with ID column of dataframe and if there is a match it will print 1 else 0

Desired output

```
      ID.         Amount.        Match
    SDFGH.       45.               0
   ASDRT.        67.               1
   AQWER.      88.                1
   TYUIIO.        543.             0
   QWERT.        32.              1
```

How can I do it in R ?

Comment: `as.integer(grepl(paste0(a, collapse = "|"), df$ID))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can remove the `.` at the end with `sub`, use `%in%` to get a logical `vector`, coerce it to binary with `as.integer` to create the 'Match' column

```
df1$Match <- as.integer(sub("\\.$", "", df1$ID) %in% a)
df1$Match
#[1] 0 1 1 0 1
```

---

Or another efficient option is `stri_detect` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
as.integer(stri_detect_regex(df1$ID, paste(a, collapse="|")))
```